# Python: Change Windows 7 master volume

Tags: python, windows, audio

I want to be able to control the master volume (not for an application, but for the current active speaker) in Python. This seems to be a tricky topic; I tried doing it in C# but I couldn't even get it to work there. Is there a way to accomplish this? (Windows 7 x64)

Please note that this question has not been answered before since my question is specifically about **Python**. Also, the project VonC is referring to there does't work on Windows 7.

Comment: You probably want to look at VonC's answer there, not the accepted answer, since you only care about Windows 7, so you don't need the much more complicated XP-compatible code.

Answer (score 4):

The easy way to do this is through [`ISimpleAudioVolume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you're using the Win32 COM wrappers from the [`pywin32`](http://starship.python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html) project, this should be pretty easy to access in Python.

As the documentation explains, there are multiple ways to get a reference to an `ISimpleAudioVolume`. You need to get a cross-process session, the way `sndvol.exe` does. See the top-level documentation on [WASAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

The pseudocode will look something like this:

```
mmde = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, None, 
                        CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator)
mmd = mmde.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eMultimedia)
mgr = mmd.Activate(IID_IAudioSessionManager)
sav = mgr.GetSimpleAudioVolume(None, True)
sav.SetMasterVolume(0.5)
```

Comment: I've just downloaded pywin32 and am a litte bit lost - I just don't know how to use it to do this. Would you be so kind to explain how to use pywin32 to accomplish this?

Comment: @user2662120: If I were to attempt to write a pywin32 client-side COM tutorial in an SO comments section, it would be far worse than the tutorials that already exist in the documentation, so why not just read them?

Comment: Personally, I think the documentation is pretty hard to read.  If you have the time, could you translate the speudocode to actual python code? I've been trying to get it working, but I'm stuck on the first line - getting the CLSID and IID...

Comment: @AndreMiras Is it possible to control the volume of separate apps with it?

Comment: @VladyVeselinov yes https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw/blob/v20160929/examples/volume_by_process_example.py