# Controlling Windows Volume Mixer with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, volume, pywin32

I was wondering how to control the volume of an application in Volume mixer in the background with python 3?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112457/python-change-windows-7-master-volume)

Comment: That question refers to the master speaker volume, I wanted to control each application's volume

Comment: That question is a starting point. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with [WinGuiAuto](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/winGuiAuto.py.html) and the python for [windows extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/).

You essentially open the Volume Control application and drive the control buttons etc programmatically. The application will normally show up on the Desktop, so that might be a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was trying to keep it in the background as this was the intention of the program. Do you know of a way that this could be done in the the background?

Comment: Some programs allow you to do that through some specific functionality ( I do that with filling in Excel sheets by driving excel from a Python app), others I use the normal interface and AFAIK that is what you need to do for the volume mixer (or look for direct volume control without going through the mixer functionality, but I have never tried that, I only did change the output device via the interface)

Comment: Put that in the question @vince2225