# Windows Volume Mixer Controller For Python

Tags: python, audio

I was wondering how to program a program that changes volume for the active program in volume mixer when a key is pressed and i it does this in the background without having to swict to volume mixer
But i dont know how to i have found some examples of it in c# but does are made to be controlled by a mirco controler there is also this question [Controlling Windows Volume Mixer with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576199/controlling-windows-volume-mixer-with-python)
but the only answer to that is a way of opening the program i dont not want to do it this since that destroys the point making the program

Comment: There is an API, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255419/how-can-i-mute-unmute-my-sound-from-powershell/19348221#19348221 but that doesn't say how to use it from Python... You can also find the code for powershell easily

Comment: Thank you you can just use pycaw to do it