# How to control windows master audio in python script

Tags: python, c++, com, pywin32, wasapi

going off of the suggestion by abarnert in [Python: Change Windows 7 master volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112457/python-change-windows-7-master-volume?lq=1)

I'm trying to write a python script to control the master volume in windows 7

I understand that in C++ this can be done like so:

```
const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
mmde = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,
    CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
    (void**)&pEnumerator);
mmd = mmde.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eMultimedia);
mgr = mmd.Activate(IID_IAudioSessionManager);
sav = mgr.GetSimpleAudioVolume(None, True);
sav.SetMasterVolume(0.5);
```

I'm trying to get that functionality in python using [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/), but I find myself stuck. The code I have so far is:

```
import pythoncom

CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator)
IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator)
mmde = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, None, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator)
mmd = mmde.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eMultimedia)
mgr = mmd.Activate(IID_IAudioSessionManager)
sav = mgr.GetSimpleAudioVolume(None, True)
sav.SetMasterVolume(0.5)
```

CoCreateInstance wants the class ID (CLSID) of the MMDeviceEnumerator, but doesn't seem to have any function like __uuidof() to use to get the class ID. (Not that I could find anyway.)

Does anyone have any ideas / suggestions? I'm new to both COM/OLE programming and pywin32 and feeling a little lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

```
PyIUnknown = CoCreateInstance(clsid, unkOuter , context , iid )
```

where 
clsid : PyIID
Class identifier (CLSID) of the object

A PyIID object is used whenever a COM GUID is used. PyIID objects can be created using the pywintypes.IID() function, although all functions that accept a GUID also accept a string in the standard GUID format.

```
PyIID = IID(iidString, is_bytes )
```

where iidString is a string representation of an IID, or a ProgID.

MMDeviceEnumerator CLSID is BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E

so try this

```
PyIID = IID("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E", is_bytes )
```

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, how did you find the CLSID of MMDeviceEnumerator?

I also need to give it the IID or GUID of the IMMDeviceEnumerator interface, but I can't seem to find it. I ssaw somewhere that the interface IIDs are listed in windows registry, but was unable to find it there.

Comment: Yes, there are in registry, Look up registry by "MMDeviceEnumerator". You will find CLSID here HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E}

Comment: @AlexTremblay if this answer worked for you, would you mind posting the working code as a second answer?  I still can't put user1's answer together with your code in the question to make a complete solution.  It seems one needs not only the `CLSID` of `MMDeviceEnumerator` (which user1 gave, along with instructions for finding it) but *also* the `IID` of `IMMDeviceEnumerator` and that's not talked about here, nor can I find it in my registry... (disclaimer: I don't know what most of these terms mean - am following blindly)